# Bestpractice ASP <-> WebApi which Auth / security model

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I'm searching for bestpractices for auth in the given Internet Application scenario.

I've an ASP MVC 4 Webpage and an ASP4 WebApi.

Both are hosted on the same server but as independent applications.
The ASP MVC4 Application consumes via RestSharp the WebApi. Also there are some 3rd Party Desktoptools planed which will use the web api.

Now I'm thinking about how to authenticate the users.

My Idea is to use Forms Authentication for the ASP MVC 4 Site and Basic Authentication for the WebApi.

Is this an good idea ?

Or should i use a token based approach for the webapi ?

What are bestpractices / concerncs for this scenario ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look at [IdentityModel 4.0](https://github.com/thinktecture/).

This is a security framework for ASP.NET Web API written by security experts.